# I am having a Bitbake Fetcher Error: UnpackError with my YOCTO PROJECT

Tags: flutter, embedded-linux, yocto

I am trying to build an image for stm32mp1 board, I want to build a flutter application with my image so when I add try to build I get do_unpack error. Here is the [link for meta-flutter layer](https://github.com/meta-flutter/meta-flutter) and here is the [link that causes I believe the unpack error](https://github.com/flutter/engine) and you can see here the .bb file at least the relevant part:

```
    SUMMARY = "Flutter Engine"
DESCRIPTION = "Google Flutter Engine for use with Flutter applications"
AUTHOR = "Flutter Team"
HOMEPAGE = "https://github.com/flutter/engineflutter/"
BUGTRACKER = "https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues"
SECTION = "graphics"
LICENSE = "BSD-3-Clause"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://flutter/LICENSE;md5=a60894397335535eb10b54e2fff9f265"
CVE_PRODUCT = "libflutter_engine.so"
REQUIRED_DISTRO_FEATURES = "opengl"
DEPENDS += "\
    compiler-rt \
    libcxx \
    zip-native \
    "
SRC_URI = "gn://github.com/flutter/engine.git;name=src/flutter \
           file://0001-clang-toolchain.patch \
           file://0002-x64-sysroot-assert.patch \
           file://0001-allow-deprecated-calls.patch \
           file://0001-remove-x11-dependency.patch \
           file://0001-prevent-redefinition-of-glib_autoptr_clear_AtkObject.patch \
```

Here is the full error lines:

```
ERROR: flutter-engine-runtimerelease-git-r0 do_unpack: Bitbake Fetcher Error: UnpackError('Unpack command PATH="/home/gencay/STM32MPU_workspace/openstlinux-5.15-yocto-kirkstone-mp1-v22.06.15/build-openstlinuxweston-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/sysroots-uninative/x86_64-linux/usr/bin:/home/gencay/STM32MPU_workspace/openstlinux-5.15-yocto-kirkstone-mp1-v22.06.15/build-openstlinuxweston-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-ostl-linux-gnueabi/flutter-engine-runtimerelease/git-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/python3-native:/home/gencay/STM32MPU_workspace/openstlinux-5.15-yocto-kirkstone-mp1-v22.06.15/layers/openembedded-core/scripts:/home/gencay/STM32MPU_workspace/openstlinux-5.15-yocto-kirkstone-mp1-v22.06.15/build-openstlinuxweston-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-ostl-linux-gnueabi/flutter-engine-runtimerelease/git-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/arm-ostl-linux-gnueabi:/home/gencay/STM32MPU_workspace/openstlinux-5.15-yocto-kirkstone-mp1-v22.06.15/build-openstlinuxweston-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-ostl-linux-gnueabi/flutter-engine-runtimerelease/git-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/bin/crossscripts:/home/gencay/STM32MPU_workspace/openstlinux-5.15-yocto-kirkstone-mp1-v22.06.15/build-openstlinuxweston-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-ostl-linux-gnueabi/flutter-engine-runtimerelease/git-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/sbin:/home/gencay/STM32MPU_workspace/openstlinux-5.15-yocto-kirkstone-mp1-v22.06.15/build-openstlinuxweston-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-ostl-linux-gnueabi/flutter-engine-runtimerelease/git-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin:/home/gencay/STM32MPU_workspace/openstlinux-5.15-yocto-kirkstone-mp1-v22.06.15/build-openstlinuxweston-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-ostl-linux-gnueabi/flutter-engine-runtimerelease/git-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/sbin:/home/gencay/STM32MPU_workspace/openstlinux-5.15-yocto-kirkstone-mp1-v22.06.15/build-openstlinuxweston-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-ostl-linux-gnueabi/flutter-engine-runtimerelease/git-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/bin:/home/gencay/STM32MPU_workspace/openstlinux-5.15-yocto-kirkstone-mp1-v22.06.15/layers/openembedded-core/bitbake/bin:/home/gencay/STM32MPU_workspace/openstlinux-5.15-yocto-kirkstone-mp1-v22.06.15/build-openstlinuxweston-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/hosttools" pbzip2 -dc -p12 /home/gencay/STM32MPU_workspace/openstlinux-5.15-yocto-kirkstone-mp1-v22.06.15/build-openstlinuxweston-stm32mp1/downloads/gn/https__github.com_flutter_engine.git-e85ea0e79c6d894c120cda4ee8ee10fe6745e187.tar.bz2 | tar x --no-same-owner -f - failed with return value 2', 'gn://github.com/flutter/engine.git;name=src/flutter')
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/gencay/STM32MPU_workspace/openstlinux-5.15-yocto-kirkstone-mp1-v22.06.15/build-openstlinuxweston-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-ostl-linux-gnueabi/flutter-engine-runtimerelease/git-r0/temp/log.do_unpack.2523161
ERROR: Task (virtual:runtimerelease:/home/gencay/STM32MPU_workspace/openstlinux-5.15-yocto-kirkstone-mp1-v22.06.15/meta-flutter/recipes-graphics/flutter-engine/flutter-engine_git.bb:do_unpack) failed with exit code '1'
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 7720 tasks of which 7703 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.
NOTE: Writing buildhistory
NOTE: Writing buildhistory took: 2 seconds

Summary: 1 task failed:
  virtual:runtimerelease:/home/gencay/STM32MPU_workspace/openstlinux-5.15-yocto-kirkstone-mp1-v22.06.15/meta-flutter/recipes-graphics/flutter-engine/flutter-engine_git.bb:do_unpack
```

Comment: Also I can not unzip the downloaded tar file inside yocto build directory manually, it says  there was an error while extracting

Answer (score 0):

You have typos in `SRC_UIR`:

```
SRC_URI = "gn://github.com/flutter/engine.git;name=src/flutter \
```

Change prefix (proto) to `git://`.